# Magento 2 : How to Use Custom AJAX Code in Admin Front End

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, ajax

I'm developing a delivery system for handling parcels that are handled the delivery agents. since I'm a open cart developer and new to magento, its hard for me to develop. Kindly tell me how to add and use my custom AJAX js directly in a needed place. I need how to access the database from controller.

Comment: Specify your requirement in detail.